# php print a single value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I want to print a single value from a multidimensional array.

I'm calling the URL `https://www.myurl.com/`
which responds with Json, such as:

```
{"data":{"country":"USA","currency":"USD","language":"American_English"}}
```

My code is:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.myurl.com/');
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

And the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [country] => USA [currency] => USD [language] => American_English ) )
```

My goal is to print only the value "American_English"

I've tried this:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.myurl.com/');
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $array[0]["language"] ;
?>
```

And I've tried this:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.myurl.com/');
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $array[0][2] ;
?>
```

And I've tried using a `foreach`:

```
json = file_get_contents('https://myurl.com');
    $decode_data = json_decode($json);

foreach($decode_data as $key=>$value){
       echo $decode_data[0]['language']; //not working
       echo $decode_data[0][2]; //not working
       print_r($value); //same result od print_r above
}
```

However none of them achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple it that

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($array);

echo $array['data']["language"] ;
```

results

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [country] => USA
            [currency] => USD
            [language] => American_English
        )

)

American_English
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.myurl.com/');
$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($array['data']['language']);
?>
```

you can use this snippet to visualize the array

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array); // or var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```